# How can i move to next array in android

Tags: android

I have some arrays like this:

```
static int [] lv1 = {R.drawable.A,R.drawable.C,R.drawable.D};
static int [] lv2 = {R.drawable.A1,R.drawable.C1,R.drawable.D1};
static int [] lv3 = {R.drawable.A2,R.drawable.C2,R.drawable.D2};
static int [] lv4 = {R.drawable.A3,R.drawable.C3,R.drawable.D3};
```

and a button.
and ImageView get Resoure random in lv1
I want to when i click on button ImageView will get Resoure random in lv2
and click more it will lv3... How can do like that?

Answer (score 1):

Code as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static int [] lv1 = {R.drawable.A,R.drawable.C,R.drawable.D};
    static int [] lv2 = {R.drawable.A1,R.drawable.C1,R.drawable.D1};
    static int [] lv3 = {R.drawable.A2,R.drawable.C2,R.drawable.D2};
    static int [] lv4 = {R.drawable.A3,R.drawable.C3,R.drawable.D3};

    private int clickTimes = 0;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id);
        findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickTimes++;
                clickTimes %= 4;
                setRandomImage();
            }
        });
        setRandomImage();
    }

    private void setRandomImage() {
        int index = getRandomIndex();
        int drawableId = -1;
        switch (clickTimes) {
        case 0:
            drawableId = lv1[index];
            break;
        case 1:
            drawableId = lv2[index];
            break;
        case 2:
            drawableId = lv3[index];
            break;
        case 3:
            drawableId = lv4[index];
            break;
        }
        if(drawableId > 0){
            imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a random int [0, 2]
     * @return
     */
    private int getRandomIndex() {
        Random randow = new Random();
        return Math.abs(randow.nextInt()) % 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a two dimensional array instead, where the first index defines the lv and the second index defines the resource inside the lv.

```
Static int lvs[][] ={
    {R.drawable.A,R.drawable.C,R.drawable.D},
    {R.drawable.A1,R.drawable.C1,R.drawable.D1},
    {R.drawable.A2,R.drawable.C2,R.drawable.D2},
    {R.drawable.A3,R.drawable.C3,R.drawable.D3}
};
```

Increase index one with each button click, set index two as random between 0 and 2.